# Why does the memory address keep changing every time I compile?

Tags: c, pointers

Why does the address of the pointed place keep changing? Whats going on inside the memory that makes this occur, or is there something wrong with my `printf` statement?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

        char blocks[3] = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

        char *ptr = &blocks[0];

        char temp;

        temp = blocks[0];
        printf(" %c, %d ", temp, &temp);

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
A, 1764940775 
A, 1731746791
```

Comment: The "pointed place" , i.e. `temp`, is a single char stack variable; not your buffer, the pointer to it, or anything related to either (though they are also on the stack). That said, do it 10,000 times and you'll see patterns form.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your stack pointer is randomized. I suspect this is because of Address Space Layout Randomization which is used as a security mechanism in most newer operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `%p` conversion specifier to printf a pointer value. But there's no reason to expect it to be the same value each time. A global or static variable, however, should be at a consistent location.